# Sharing code with students

Tags: c#, sharing

I teach programming (C# in Visual Studio) and I typically programmering small examples of code together with the students on the projector in the classroom.

Afterwards the students would like to continue working with the exsample. Right now I zip the entire C# project folder together and share via Google Drive.

Is there any smarter/simpler way to share?

Comment: What about GitHub?

Comment: https://classroom.github.com/

Comment: Also, make sure you tell them not to come to Stack Overflow to ask off topic questions... :)

Answer (score 1):

I would setup a GitLab on a private server and just give them clone access... but there are plenty of source version control and plateforms available.